# Separate process will be killed after main process terminated

Tags: python, process

I created a new separate by
(test.py):

```
import os, time
os.system("nohup watch -n1 'ls' &")
time.sleep(100)
```

after 100 seconds the test.py will be finished and the watch process is exist (because it's separate process not child); 
But why the watch process will be killed if i terminate the test.py before 100 seconds?

Comment: any comment??!!

Comment: Please tell me do you get same result or not...